# Javascript: Check if any elements in an array contain a part of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an array of "banned domains", and I'm trying to find an easy way to check if a particular email is from one of those domains. Consider the following:

```
var bannedDoms = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", ".le.salesforce.com"]
if(bannedDoms.indexOf(email.split("@")[1]) === -1){
   // It's a good domain!
}
```

This works fine, except for the last example, as the `salesforce` emails are from weird domains like **`emailtosalesforce@t-1l9sefi2sef5wlowk59bvm0uuh78mkdfuhioamfu7vxv8agjjh.o-h7zieac.na17.le.salesforce.com`** - the common factor being that they all have `.le.salesforce.com` in the address.

Searching via `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is quite an elegant solution and I'd like to use something similar if possible - but to also catch parts of strings, rather than a whole string match.

What's the most efficient and simple way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: You will have iterate through the array and check

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a regex:

```
/gmail\.com|hotmail\.com|\le\.salesforce\.com/.test("emailtosalesforce@t-1l9sefi2sef5wlowk59bvm0uuh78mkdfuhioamfu7vxv8agjjh.o-h7zieac.na17.le.salesforce.com")
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0ske3x24/1/)

```
var bannedDoms = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", ".le.salesforce.com"];
r=new RegExp(bannedDoms.map(function(x){ return x.replace(/\./g,'\\.') }).join("|"));
```

Explanation:

You could simply build up a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), taking each banned domain and combine them with `or`. The simplest form would be `a|b`, *read* `a or b`. In principle `gmail.com or hotmail.com` would become `gmail.com|hotmail.com` - with one exception: `.` is a special character in a regular expression *meaning* `any character`. To cirumvent this, we need to `escape` the dot to `\.`.

```
r=new RegExp(bannedDoms.map(function(x){ return x.replace(/\./g,'\\.') }).join("|"));
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function, which applies a *function* onto each element of an array - returning the resulting array.

The map-part does nothing more than *replacing* every occuring `.` with an escaped version `\.`.

[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) joins the resulting array-elements with a *pipe* = `or`.

Thanks @torazaburo

Comment: I was impeded by external factors - so to say ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `replace(".", "\\.")`? Otherwise JS will eat the backslash when parsing the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to iterate and test the domains like

```js
var bannedDoms = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", ".le.salesforce.com"];

function isBanned(email) {
  var domain = email.split("@")[1];

  var banned = bannedDoms.some(function(value) {
    return domain.indexOf(value) > -1;
  })
  if (!banned) {
    // It's a good domain!
  }

  snippet.log(email + ' : ' + banned);
}

isBanned('asdf@gmail.com');
isBanned('asdf@hotmail.com');
isBanned('asdf@.le.salesforce.com');
isBanned('asdf@abc.com');
isBanned('asdf@test.com');
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to do a string indexOf, if you want to catch those.
So, You can try something like this..

```
var bannedDoms = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", ".le.salesforce.com"]
for(var i=0; i<bannedDoms.length; i++) {
    if(email.indexOf(bannedDoms[i]) === -1){
         // It's a good domain!
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `for` instead of `for ...in`

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good candidate for the `endsWith` simulation:

```js
var bannedDoms = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", ".le.salesforce.com"];
var email1 = "emailtosalesforce@t-asd.o-h7zieac.na17.le.salesforce.com";
var email2 = "emailtosalesforce@t-asd.o-h7zieac.na17.le.salesforce.net";

console.log(bannedDoms.some(function (e) {
    return email1.indexOf(e, email1.length - e.length) !== -1;
})); // true

console.log(bannedDoms.some(function (e) {
    return email2.indexOf(e, email2.length - e.length) !== -1;
})); // false
```